# Is there a countable model?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

If we consider $\mathcal{L}=\{R\}$ a binary relation and a consistant theory $T$ can I affirm that there exists a countable model ?

It seems to be a consequence of Löwenhein-Skolem's result with $\mathcal{L}$ which is countable and $T$ consistant.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Assuming $\mathcal{L}$ is a first order language, it meets the criteria for the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem...

Comment: @MaliceVidrine So there will still be a countable model with these hypothesis according to that theorem ?

Comment: Yes, this is what the theorem says.

Comment: Assuming that $T$ has infinite models, of course.

Comment: @Nagase but does "$T$ has an infinite model" come from the fact that $T$ is consistant ?

Comment: @Maman No, it does not. Take for example the theory consisting of the formula $\forall x \forall y (R(x,y) \wedge ((R(x,y) \implies x = y))$. This theory is consistent, but all of its models have exactly one element.

Comment: @Stefan indeed thanks

Comment: If you take countable to mean, countably infinite or finite (some authors do this), then this is the completeness theorem. If you take countable to mean countably infinite, then @Stefan 's comment holds. So it really depends on how you interpret the words.

Comment: "Countable" is properly equivalent to "countably infinite or finite". The incorrect usage of "countable" to mean "countably infinite" is an abuse of terminology, although one does occasionally see it.  This usage also goes against common sense: clearly a set should be "countable" if it's possible to count or enumerate its members; it mystifies me that anybody would say something that implicitly implies that one can't count the members of a finite set.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: I thoroughly agree with your sentiment, but, sadly, I think it's a lost battle. I suspect that part of the problem is that "denumerable" is (equally stupidly) used to mean countably infinite and one stupid usage encourages another ("denumerable" sounds like "enumerable" and "enumerate" means count so ...).